# Remove duplicate strings within a pandas dataframe entry

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to remove duplicate strings within a pandas dataframe entry. But Im only find solutions for removing duplicate rows.

The entries I want to clean look like this:

[image]

Dataframe looks like this:

[image]

I want each string between the commas to occur only once.
Can someone please help me?

Comment: please show how the df looks like in a shape of df

Comment: I did, if that is what you meant

Comment: I didn't understand what you want since the 'cleaned data' you give still have duplicate string.

Comment: and exactly these dublicate strings I want to remove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (I've added a simple example of my own df):

```
import pandas as pd

data = ['a,b,c','a,b,b,e,d','a,a,e,d,f']
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns={"cleaned_data"})

def remove_dups_letters(row):
    sentences = set(row.split(","))
    new_str = ','.join(sentences)
    return new_str

df['cleaned_data'] = df['cleaned_data'].apply(remove_dups_letters)
print(df)
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much!